# Matlab: allowing cursor and keyboard input simultaneously

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to display a plot, and then wait for *either* the cursor to be clicked on the plot, *or* the user to enter a number into Matlab by pressing a key. So far, I know how to both of these individually, but I don't know how to allow Matlab to response to both independently. I suppose you would call this a form of multi-threading.

My code to enable a response when the cursor is clicked is as follows:

```
h = figure( %{ ... params ...%} );
while true
    figure(h);
    cursor = ginput(1);
    % ... process the cursor input ...
end
```

Now, I want to include the following line to enable the user to input a number from the keyboard:

```
num = input('Enter the number: ' );
```

But if I just add this to my while loop:

```
h = figure( %{ ... params ...%} );
while true
    figure(h);
    cursor = ginput(1);
    % ... process the cursor input ...
    num = input('Enter the number: ' ); 
    % ... process the keyboard input ...
end
```

Then the program will always wait for the user to enter a number from the keyboard before returning to look for a cursor input. But I want the program to respond to both independently of each other.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can get the desired result with ginput and input.
An alternartive approach is to add callback functions to your figure:

```
function mouse_and_keyboard_input()
    %set up a figure with keypress and mouseclick event
    figure('KeyPressFcn',@keyPress, 'WindowButtonDownFcn', @mouseClicked)
    plot(sin(0:0.1:2*pi));

    h_text = text(10, -0.8, 'No key pressed');
    h_mouse = text(10, -0.6, 'No mouse click');

        % Nested function: variables are shared.
        function keyPress(objectHandle, eventData)
            key = get(objectHandle,'CurrentCharacter');
            set(h_text, 'string', ['Last pressed key: ' key])
        end 
        function mouseClicked(objectHandle , eventData )
            disp('mouse clicked')
            pos = get(objectHandle,'CurrentPoint'); 
            set(h_mouse, 'string', ['Mouse click pos: ' num2str(pos)])
        end 
end
```

If you click into the figure, the function *mouseClicked* will be called and the mouse position in the figure will be displayed. 
Here you could add further code of yours to *process the cursor input*